# Laravel relaciones n-n a tres tablas

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, eloquent

Tengo tres tablas. Una es de tareas para gestionar, la otra es de los responsables de realizarlas y la otra es de ciudades donde se realizan. Además tengo una tabla pivote que debe relacionar las tres tablas, mediante los id. La tabla pivote, además, debe llevar un indicador de si la tarea está o no activa (un campo con un `0` o un `1`, que se llama `activa`).

Las migraciones son las siguientes. La de la tabla de tareas (`tasks`) es así:

```
<?php

use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Schema;
use Illuminate\Database\Schema\Blueprint;
use Illuminate\Database\Migrations\Migration;

class CreateTasksTable extends Migration
{
    public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('tasks', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->increments('id');
            $table->string('tarea', 100);
            $table->text('descripcion')->nullable();
            $table->date('f_inicio');
            $table->date('f_final');
            $table->timestamps();
        });
    }

    public function down()
    {
        Schema::dropIfExists('tasks');
    }
}
```

La de la tabla de responsables (`managers`) es así:

```
<?php

use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Schema;
use Illuminate\Database\Schema\Blueprint;
use Illuminate\Database\Migrations\Migration;

class CreateManagersTable extends Migration
{
    public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('managers', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->increments('id');
            $table->string('nombre', 60);
            $table->string('cargo', 60);
            $table->timestamps();
        });
    }

    public function down()
    {
        Schema::dropIfExists('managers');
    }
}
```

La de la tabla de ciudades (`cities`) es así:

```
<?php

use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Schema;
use Illuminate\Database\Schema\Blueprint;
use Illuminate\Database\Migrations\Migration;

class CreateCitiesTable extends Migration
{
    public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('cities', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->increments('id');
            $table->string('ciudad', 60);
            $table->string('pais', 60);
            $table->timestamps();
        });
    }

    public function down()
    {
        Schema::dropIfExists('cities');
    }
}
```

La de la tabla pivote (`city_manager_task`) es así:

```
<?php

use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Schema;
use Illuminate\Database\Schema\Blueprint;
use Illuminate\Database\Migrations\Migration;

class CreateCitiesManagersTasksTable extends Migration
{
    public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('city_manager_task', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->increments('id');

            $table->integer('city_id')->unsigned();
            $table->foreign('city_id')->references('id')->on('cities');

            $table->integer('manager_id')->unsigned();
            $table->foreign('manager_id')->references('id')->on('managers');

            $table->integer('task_id')->unsigned();
            $table->foreign('task_id')->references('id')->on('tasks');

            $table->char('activa', 1);
            $table->timestamps();
        });
    }

    public function down()
    {
        Schema::dropIfExists('city_manager_task');
    }
}
```

Los modelos los tengo definidos así. El modelo de ciudades (`City`) es así:

```
<?php

namespace App;

use App\Manager;
use App\Task;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class City extends Model
{
    protected $table = 'cities';
    protected $fillable = [
        'ciudad',
        'pais',
    ];

    public function managers()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany(Manager::class, 'city_manager_task')->withTimestamps()->withPivot('activa');
    }

    public function tasks()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany(Task::class, 'city_manager_task')->withTimestamps()->withPivot('activa');
    }
}
```

El modelo de responsables (`Manager`) es así:

```
<?php

namespace App;

use App\City;
use App\Task;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Manager extends Model
{
    protected $table = 'managers';
    protected $fillable = [
        'nombre',
        'cargo',
    ];

    public function cities()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany(City::class, 'city_manager_task')->withTimestamps()->withPivot('activa');
    }

    public function tasks()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany(Task::class, 'city_manager_task')->withTimestamps()->withPivot('activa');
    }
}
```

El modelo de tareas (`Task`) es así:

```
<?php

namespace App;

use App\City;
use App\Manager;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Task extends Model
{
    protected $table = 'tasks';
    protected $fillable = [
        'tarea',
        'descripcion',
        'f_inicio',
        'f_final',
    ];

    public function cities()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany(City::class, 'city_manager_task')->withTimestamps()->withPivot('activa');
    }

    public function managers()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany(Manager::class, 'city_manager_task')->withTimestamps()->withPivot('activa');
    }
}
```

El último modelo es el de la tabla pivote (`CityManagerTask`) es asi:

```
namespace App;

use App\City;
use App\Manager;
use App\Task;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Relations\Pivot;

class CityManagerTask extends Pivot
{
    protected $table = 'city_manager_task';
    protected $fillable = [
        'city_id',
        'manager_id',
        'task_id',
        'activa',
    ];
}
```

Las factories también las tengo. La de ciudades (`CityFactory`) es así:

```
<?php

use Faker\Generator as Faker;

$factory->define(App\City::class, function (Faker $faker) {
    return [
        'ciudad' => $faker->city,
        'pais' => $faker->country
    ];
});
```

La de responsables (`ManagerFactory`) es así:

```
<?php

use Faker\Generator as Faker;

$factory->define(App\Manager::class, function (Faker $faker) {
    return [
        'nombre' => $faker->name(),
        'cargo' => $faker->randomElement([
            'Team leader',
            'Controller',
            'Advisor',
            'Manager'
        ]),
    ];
});
```

La de tareas (`TaskFactory`) es así:

```
<?php

use Faker\Generator as Faker;

$factory->define(App\Task::class, function (Faker $faker) {
    return [
        'tarea' => $faker->randomElement([
            'Gestión de marketing',
            'Control de divisas',
            'Mobiliario urbano',
            'Medición de ruido',
            'Creación de equipos',
            'Estructuración de paisajes'
        ]),
        'descripcion' => $faker->sentence(20),
        'f_inicio' => $faker->dateTimeInInterval('- 2 years', '+ 6 months'),
        'f_final' => $faker->dateTimeInInterval('- 1 years', '+ 6 months'),
    ];
});
```

Por último, el seeder (DatabaseSeeder) para que se ejecuten las factories es el siguiente:

```
<?php

use App\City;
use App\Manager;
use App\Task;

use Illuminate\Database\Seeder;

class DatabaseSeeder extends Seeder
{
    public function run()
    {
        $cities = factory(City::class, 20)->create();
        $managers = factory(Manager::class, 10)->create();
        factory(Task::class, 100)->create()
            ->each(function ($task) use ($cities, $managers)
                {
                    $task->cities()
                        ->attach($cities
                            ->random(mt_rand(5, 15))
                            ->pluck('id')
                        )->managers()
                        ->attach($managers)
                            ->pluck('id');
                }
            );
    }
}
```

Las migraciones se están ejecutando bien, y se crean perfectamente las estructuras, con sus claves foráneas, sin problemas. El problema viene cuando trato de ejecutar el seeder, para que ejecute las factories. Se supone que debe llenar las tres tablas de datos (eso sí lo hace bien), pero, además, debe cumplimentar la tabla pivote. Al ejecutarlo, me responde:

```
Illuminate\Database\QueryException  : SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 19 NOT NULL constraint failed: city_manager_task.manager_id (SQL: insert into "city_manager_task" ("city_id", "created_at", "task_id", "updated_at") select 2 as "city_id", 2019-01-11 12:47:54 as "created_at", 1 as "task_id", 2019-01-11 12:47:54 as "updated_at" union all select 3 as "city_id", 2019-01-11 12:47:54 as "created_at", 1 as "task_id", 2019-01-11 12:47:54 as "updated_at" union all select 7 as "city_id", 2019-01-11 12:47:54 as "created_at", 1 as "task_id", 2019-01-11 12:47:54 as "updated_at" union all select 8 as "city_id", 2019-01-11 12:47:54 as "created_at", 1 as "task_id", 2019-01-11 12:47:54 as "updated_at" union all select 9 as "city_id", 2019-01-11 12:47:54 as "created_at", 1 as "task_id", 2019-01-11 12:47:54 as "updated_at" union all select 10 as "city_id", 2019-01-11 12:47:54 as "created_at", 1 as "task_id", 2019-01-11 12:47:54 as "updated_at" union all select 12 as "city_id", 2019-01-11 12:47:54 as "created_at", 1 as "task_id", 2019-01-11 12:47:54 as "updated_at" union all select 19 as "city_id", 2019-01-11 12:47:54 as "created_at", 1 as "task_id", 2019-01-11 12:47:54
as "updated_at")

  at C:\xampp\htdocs\trestablas\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Database\Connection.php:664
    660|         // If an exception occurs when attempting to run a query, we'll format the error
    661|         // message to include the bindings with SQL, which will make this exception a
    662|         // lot more helpful to the developer instead of just the database's errors.
    663|         catch (Exception $e) {
  > 664|             throw new QueryException(
    665|                 $query, $this->prepareBindings($bindings), $e
    666|             );
    667|         }
    668|

  Exception trace:

  1   PDOException::("SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 19 NOT NULL constraint failed: city_manager_task.manager_id")
      C:\xampp\htdocs\trestablas\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Database\Connection.php:458

  2   PDOStatement::execute()
      C:\xampp\htdocs\trestablas\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Database\Connection.php:458
```

Y, no tengo ni idea de qué estoy haciendo mal. Lo que sea, está en el seeder, creo. Además, necesito que al cumplimentar la tabla pivote me introduzca, en cada registro, en el campo `activa`, el valor `0` o `1`.
Es decir. Cada registro de la tabla pivote debería tener el id de una tarea, el de un responsable, el de una ciudad, y el valor que indique si la tarea está activa o no.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

El problema es la forma como están definidas las relaciones con la tabla pivote (la cual definiste como un modelo), puesto que no tienes en cuenta la llave de la tabla no involucrada.

En Task tienes:

```
public function cities()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany(City::class, 'city_manager_task')->withTimestamps()->withPivot('activa');
}

public function managers()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany(Manager::class, 'city_manager_task')->withTimestamps()->withPivot('activa');
}
```

Básicamente el seeder falla cuando intenta agregar la relación con cities porque en dicha relación no está incluida la llave de manager `'manager_id`, y dicho campo no puede ser null. En todo caso, si funcionara, generaría dos registros en la tabla pivote, uno para cities y otro para managers.

Teniendo en cuenta que Laravel no puede manejar de forma nativa una relación de tres tablas con una pivote, puedes solucionarlo de varias formas, tal vez la que más sigue las convenciones de Laravel es la de agregar la llave en mención a la relación como campo adicional:

```
public function cities()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany(City::class, 'city_manager_task')->withTimestamps()->withPivot('manager_id', 'activa');
}
```

Podrías también hacer lo mismo para managers.

---

En cuanto al seeder, ya no sería necesario intentar agregar las dos relaciones a la tabla pivote, todo se haría a partir de una sola, en este caso lo haremos con cities:

```
$task->cities()
    ->attach(
        $cities
        ->random(mt_rand(5, 15))
        ->pluck('id'),
        [
            'manager_id' => $managers->random()->id,
            'activa' => mt_rand(0, 1)
        ]
    );
```

Los dos campos adicionales de la tabla los pasamos como segundo parámetro del método attach, en este caso como un array.

Comment: Mil gracias, Shaz. Lo has clavado. Además, haciéndolo como me has dicho, no aparece el problema ese que mencionas de generar dos registros en la tabla pivote, uno para cada relación. Es genial, por lo simple, y porque a mi no se me habría ocurrido en mil años. Solo una aclaración. El manager_id lo he puesto en el método cities de Task, como me indicas. Debería añadirlo en el mismo método del modelo Manager para luego poder hacer lecturas y escrituras? Aunque creo que no es relevante, estoy usando SQLite, no MySQL. Gracias.

Comment: Perdona, no habia visto donde dices lo de añadirlo en Manager. Gracias.

Comment: Hola. No sé si este es el sitio adecuado para extender la pregunta. Cuando leo las tareas, como puedo obtener los datos de la ciudad, el responsable y el estado? Sé que puedo leer las tareas con Task::all(), lo que me devuelve una colección, y a partir de cada objeto Task puedo leer los datos de cada ciudad asociada, pero no los de los gestores y el estado u otros datos de la tabla pivote. Podeis ayudarme? Gracias

Comment: Debes formular una nueva pregunta.